# Thorntail create datasource connection in postgres in openshift

Tags: postgresql, openshift, thorntail

I have a java app that use thorntail, postgres DB and i want to deploy this app to openshift via docker image.

I have tested successful build app with docker image and deploy to minishift and external postgres DB.

And now I want to use postgres in openshift instead of external postgres

But I dont know how to **specify postgres connection for openshift** in **project-defaults.yml**.

This is my project-defaults.yml: It does't work for postgres in openshift

```
thorntail:
  datasources:
    data-sources:
      postgres_tenancy:
        driver-name: mypostgres
        connection-url: postgresql://postgresql:5432/$POSTGRESQL_DATABASE
        user-name: $POSTGRESQL_USER
        password: $POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD
    jdbc-drivers:
      mypostgres:
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
        xa-datasource-name: org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource
        driver-module-name: org.postgresql
```

Anybody has any idea?

Comment: How is the PostgreSQL database in OpenShift deployed? Specifying the `postgresql` domain name should work, if there's a Service for the database.

Comment: Can you explain clearly about that? I'm totally new about openshift.
But you can see that link below for postgres app and service. 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1z6nrBJmgT7x33QMgGdVxbeD_drMUmwCX

Comment: Clearly the service is there and points to a running pod, so that's OK. I'm just looking at some tests I did, and have one question: did you perhaps forget to add `jdbc:` at the beginning of the connection URL? The full URL should look like `jdbc:postgresql://test-db:5432/testdb`.

Comment: I have try with full url connection but it still not work jdbc:postgresql://postgresql:5432/$POSTGRESQL_DATABASE
do you have any other idea? Or the project-defaults.yml dont allow to have env openshift

Comment: At this point, I'm not really sure what could be wrong. Is there something interesting in the log of the application pod?

Comment: In log file there is only one word "Killed" https://drive.google.com/open?id=1j6Try4GCTpw7BvCO0w_jpwef4BZm0HwH
hoặc 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=18T_FglM8DblwRmEi42sZpgc87DQ9IVUr

Comment: You showed a log of the deployment. Can you show a log of the pod? It seems it's being constantly restarted (see "Crash Loop Back-off" on picture "4-error.png"). That might be because it can't reach the database, and I wonder if there's something interesting about that in the log.

Comment: Is this one? https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xq9tYVOlGAxWJqD07dIyBqRKW5yXR_Mq

Comment: This is a configure screen in postgres. Do i need to change something?https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oISepQXeUUXlmPT1qQtrdRyZnNdeo0oQ

Comment: Hmm, the pod log also contains just "Killed"? That's weird. I'd expect that it should be possible to see the usual Thorntail startup log sequence, if you open the pod log at the time it isn't killed yet.

Comment: First you need to ensure that there is a service in openshift with the name and port used in your connectuon url as @Ladicek already mentioned and that the pod is running and postgres is ready to accept connections. Are the service ports mapped to the container proper port? Then ensure that the parameters you use are set as system properties. If you get an error what does it say and what connection url is it actually using? Could you provide the logs?

Comment: One thing that occured to me: could it perhaps be the OOM killer killing the app? Do you set any resource requests/limits? Another option is, given that the screenshots seem to be from OpenShift Online Starter, that there is too much pods running already. OpenShift Online Starter gives you a very small quota and it isn't hard to hit the quota. After that, nothing else will run.